# Get the html input elements using loop in servlet

Tags: html, loops, servlets, request

I am developing a web application. In that, I have named the html input elements as `textfield[i][j]`.

How to get those elements in servlet?

```
String table_array[][] = new String[rows][cols];
for (int i=0; i<rows; i++) {
    for ( int j=0; j<cols; j++){ 
        table_array[i][j] = request.getParameter("label"+[i]+[j]+""); // here im facing problem to access the element. 
    }
}
```

How to access the `label[i][j]` values from request parameter?

Comment: Please edit your question and post the relevant JSP code.

Comment: There's no such thing as nested arrays in html `input` elements.  Post the HTML code in question.